# JOIN Nested DISTINCT

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, nested, distinct

I am writing SQL statements with MS Access and I am wondering how I can nest a SELECT DISTINCT statement in my JOIN?

At the moment I am writing 2 queries to get an output (2 steps):

1st query is a simple DISTINCT statement.
2nd query is a JOIN on the query created in 1.

How can I nest a DISTINCT statement in the join in order to perform the action in a single step?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.ISIN, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode
FROM tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos;


SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, QSelDistinctISINs.IssuerCode
FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN QSelDistinctISINs ON QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN = QSelDistinctISINs.ISIN;
```

I was thinking about something like the below but the syntax is wrong…

```
SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode
FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos ON SELECT DISTINCT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN = tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.ISIN;
```

Comment: Does something like `... JOIN tbl ON col IN (SELECT ..)` work?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Just tried your suggestion... but the below did not work either: 'SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode
FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos ON
IN (SELECT DISTINCT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN FROM QSel_CollateralReposII) = tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.ISIN;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test what is allowed and what is not in Access but you can replace `QSelDistinctISINs` in your query with the query that defines it, by just putting it inside parenthesis and giving it an alias - `d` below. This is valid SQL syntax:

```
SELECT 
    r.ISIN, 
    r.MarketValueUSD, 
    d.IssuerCode
FROM 
    QSel_CollateralReposII  r
  INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
          ISIN,
          IssuerCode
      FROM 
          tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos
    ) d
    ON r.ISIN = d.ISIN ;
```

Comment: I tried with and without an Alias and I get "Syntax Error in Join Operation". I get the feeling Access cannot handle such join. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Did you use the query exactly as above?

Comment: the syntax of your script would be rejected by MS Access. I tried:

SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode
FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode FROM tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos) ON QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN = tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.ISIN;

Comment: Using Alias I tried:
 SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode
FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode FROM tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos) as MyAlias ON QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN = MyAlias;

Comment: It should be `SELECT QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN, QSel_CollateralReposII.MarketValueUSD, MyAlias.IssuerCode FROM QSel_CollateralReposII INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.ISIN, tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos.IssuerCode FROM tblFinalIssuerNames_ReverseRepos) as MyAlias ON QSel_CollateralReposII.ISIN = MyAlias.ISIN; `

Comment: It's confirmed, Access cannot handle a nested SELECT statement in a JOIN. I now get a notification that I cannot view the architecture in Design View... It basically perceives MyAlias.ISIN as a parameter. Thanks for the script, which will help for my SQL Server projects.

Comment: I thought it could but perhaps I was wrong. What version of Access do you use?

Comment: Not being able to see it in Design View is common for complex queries. Can you run the query or it does produce syntax error when you run it?

Comment: 2010 - Access is quite limited when it comes to JOIN.

Comment: I had forgotten to replace the table name with MyAlias in the first SELECT statement, it now runs fine. Sorry and thank you!